# How show display all data using fetch method in React.js

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am Beginning in Programming. Now am trying to show All data in the display using the fetch data method. But Couldn't show this.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useProducts = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://damp-island-69804.herokuapp.com/inventory")
            .then(res => res.json)
            .then(data => setItems(data))
    }, [])
    return [items, setItems];
}
export default useProducts;
```

What's the problem with this code? Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please note `res => res.json` in your code should be `res.json()` as it is a function not property.

Answer (score 0):

Refer This example : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/

1. Use resp.json() instead of resp.json
2. Check resp.ok if not throw exception. Then set the exception message in another state variable.
3. If loader used, show and hide accordingly by using the setter.
4. Add try and catch accordingly And do clean up in the finally block.